# Passing null values to the parameter in controller after submit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The below code  is sample I typed
After I submit passing null values to controller, In Controller I have used the Class name then value passing correctly but when i used the parameter it passing NULL values to the controller. Please give me a solution..

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string firstname)
        {
            LogonViewModel lv = new LogonViewModel();
            var ob = s.Newcustomer(firstname)

            return View(ob );
        }
```

View:

```
@model IList<clientval.Models.LogonViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {  
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].UserName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(per => per[i].UserName)

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
}
```

Model:

```
 public class LogonViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is Required")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }



    public List<ShoppingClass> Newcustomer(string firstname1)
        {

            List<ShoppingClass> list = new List<ShoppingClass>();
           ..
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working.. I have changed my controller as written below

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IList<LogonViewModel> obj)
        {

            LogonViewModel lv = new LogonViewModel();
            var ob = lv.Newcustomer(obj[0].FirstName)

            return View(ob );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

Does not give you this in your view:

```
@model IList<clientval.Models.LogonViewModel>
```

And this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {  
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].UserName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(per => per[i].UserName)

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Will not work with this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string firstname) {
      LogonViewModel lv = new LogonViewModel();
      var ob = s.Newcustomer(firstname)
      return View(ob );
}
```

You're not sending a model to your view, and you're using a list in your view, but expecting a single string value in you controller. Something is very strange/wrong with your example, or your code.

Why do you have a IList as your model? If all you need is to render a form with a single input field. You should have code like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View(new LogonViewModel());
}
```

And the view:

```
@model clientval.Models.LogonViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And the second action on the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LogonViewModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      // TODO: Whatever logic is needed here!
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: just for example I typed this one, but actually I am passing many parameters in my controller...

Comment: Kind of hard spotting an error, if the example is not pretty close to the actual code, and your example is odd.